# Trigger with if else condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to MySQL trigger.  I want to make a trigger that before the update is made from my `emp_audit` table will check first if the `empno` from my employees table already exists. If it exists then do the update otherwise do nothing.

I encounter the following error:

> Error 1064

The code is:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_emp_audit_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON emp_audit
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE empno = NEW.empno) = 1
  THEN
  UPDATE INTO emp_audit
  SET ACTION = 'update',
  empno = NEW.empno,
  lastname = NEW.lastname,
  changedat = NOW();

  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPDATE syntax does not include the INTO keyword.

Comment: tnx for you sharp eyes...it wrks now,thnk you

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below updated query works.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_emp_audit_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON emp_audit
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE empno = NEW.empno) = 1
  THEN
  UPDATE INTO emp_audit
  SET ACTION = 'update',
  empno = NEW.empno,
  lastname = NEW.lastname,
  changedat = NOW()
  WHERE empno = NEW.empno;

  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

I think, you can even remove the empno from you SET(update) list and try the below query,

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_emp_audit_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON emp_audit
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE empno = NEW.empno) = 1
  THEN
  UPDATE INTO emp_audit
  SET ACTION = 'update',
  lastname = NEW.lastname,
  changedat = NOW()
  WHERE empno = NEW.empno;

  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```